# Don't think my scene is lit properly? opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, lighting

i'm trying to implement a lighting in my vertex shader however, there doesn't seem to be much change on the vertex's colour.

```
#version 330
```

structured layout for vertex attributes

```
layout (location = 0 ) in vec3 vertex_position;

layout (location = 1 ) in vec3 vertex_color;

layout (location = 2 ) in vec3 vertex_normal;
```

/// uniform variables

```
uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 NormalMatrix;

uniform vec3 AmbientFinal;
```

///struct to handle light info and material info

```
 struct lightInfo
{
    vec3 LightPosition;
    vec3 ambientLightInt;
    vec3 diffuseLightInt;
    vec3 SpecularLightInt;
};

uniform lightInfo lights;

struct MaterialInfo
{
    vec3 ka;
    vec3 kd;
    vec3 ks;
    float Shineness;
};

uniform MaterialInfo material;

out vec3 colour;
```

lighting calculations in main

```
void main()
{
  ///light position in eye coordinates
  vec4 lighteye =   ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(lights.LightPosition, 1.0f);         
  vec3 tnorm = normalize(mat3(NormalMatrix) *  vertex_normal);
```

///position in eyecoords

```
vec4 eyeCoords = ViewMatrix*ModelMatrix* vec4(vertex_position, 1.f);

   vec3 s = normalize(vec3(lighteye - eyeCoords));
   vec3 v = normalize(-eyeCoords.xyz);
   vec3 r = reflect(-s, tnorm);
   vec3 ambient = material.ka * lights.ambientLightInt;
   float sdotn = max(dot(s, tnorm),0.0);
   vec3 diffuse = lights.diffuseLightInt * material.kd * sdotn;
   vec3 spec = vec3(0.0);
   if(sdotn > 0)
   spec = lights.SpecularLightInt * material.ks * pow (max(dot(r,v), 0.0), material.Shineness);


  gl_Position =  ProjectionMatrix *ViewMatrix*ModelMatrix* vec4(vertex_position, 1.f);
  colour =  (diffuse + ambient + spec)  + vertex_color;
}
```

produced output

[image: output from running program]

ouput without lighting calculations

[image: output without lighting]

These are the variables

```
///lights and Mats
lightInfo lights;
lights.LightPosition =   glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f,  2.f);
lights.ambientLightInt = glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
lights.diffuseLightInt = glm::vec3(1.f);
lights.SpecularLightInt = glm::vec3(1.f);

MaterialInfo mat;
mat.ka = glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
mat.kd = glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
mat.ks = glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
mat.Shineness = 30.f;
```

Prehaps my understanding of lighting is wrong? i don't get why the 3d object isn't really being affected by the lighting calculations

[image: Hard coded the term]

Comment: For a quick debuging, use single values (diffuse, or ambient, or spec or vertex_color) and see the results. Also be aware of clamping values to [0, 1.0] range.

Comment: Per vertex lighting is not a good decision for a quad with 4 vertices. Do the light calculations per fragment.

Comment: @Ripi2  I changed my variables to single values 1.f but there is still no effect. I think you're onto something with clamping, i think i'm supppose to  clamp the value from diffuse

Comment: @Rabbid76 i'll try doing it per fragment but  why isn't it a good idea to do it in vertex is it because of the way it interpolates it in later stages

Comment: Now you debugged... Do you see that ambient and diffuse are factors (`*` instead of `+`) to material color? IOW, why do you add `vertex_color`?

Comment: Yes, because of the interpolation. The light is only calculated for the 4 vertex coordinates, which are the corners of the quad. If the light is spotted to the center of the quad, this information is lost. Per vertex lighting is an "old" technique, caused by the low performance of graphics cards in the past.

Comment: `lights.LightPosition` probably is a world space coordinate, so it is sufficient to transform by the `ViewMatrix`

Comment: @Ripi It is absolut ok to sum the color. Either `(diffuse + ambient + spec) + vertex_color` or `(diffuse + ambient + spec) * vertex_color`, both is common.

Comment: @Darman Try to put the light position near a corner of the quad, for debug reasons. But note, there won't be any light, if the normal vector is not proper set and is directed out of the view, towards the point of view.

Comment: @Rabbid76 i think you were write about the clamping issues, for some reason the ambient term works but doesn't work at the same time. If i hardcode the lights.ambientlightint to a value of 0.5f. It seems to show but if i change the actual vec3 to 0.5f it stops showings. Added the image above